# How can I get the week day of day after tomorrow and the day next?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to show the forecast on a weather app of the next three days. For "Tomorrow" I'm not complicating myself so I just display "Tomorrow", but I need to display also the day after tomorrow and the day next too ->

So I can display "tomorrow: 21º/13º, [day-after-tomorrow]=.... , [day-next] = .... "

I'm trying to get that using the getDay() method and because it returns an array from 0 to 6 I'm trying to compare it with an array I've made of the day week in the same order that the method returns to say to the program: "Hey, if you get getDay === 1, then display this position on my array "days[1]" (which is a string "Monday"). But I'm doing something wrong and can't get the feedback I'm looking for.

```
function calculateDay () {
    const days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    let today = new Date();
    let currentDay = today.getDay();
    let trueDay;
    let afterTom = trueDay + 1;
    let dayNext = trueDay + 2;

    if (currentDay === 0) {
        trueDay === days[0];
    } 
}
```

I'm pretty lost on that and can't figure out how to get the feedback and how to get the TWO different feedback data (day after tomorrow and the day next).

Any help would be appreciated by this front-end Padawan.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do, is when you increase a day, check if it is not bigger than 6. If it is, so you need to restart the count, setting the day to `0`.

Below code will help you to understand in a very readable way.

```js
const days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];


function calculateDay() {
  let today = new Date();
  let currentDay = today.getDay();
  console.log("Today:", days[currentDay])

  let tomorrow = currentDay + 1; //INCREASE A DAY
  if (tomorrow > 6) { //CHECK IF IS BIGGER THAN 6 (6 = saturday)
    tomorrow = 0;
  }
  console.log("Tomorrow:", days[tomorrow])

  let dayAfter = tomorrow + 1;
  if (dayAfter > 6) {
    dayAfter = 0;
  }
  console.log("Day After Tomorrow:", days[dayAfter])

  let thirdDay = dayAfter + 1;
  if (thirdDay > 6) {
    thirdDay = 0;
  }
  console.log("Third Day:", days[thirdDay])

}

calculateDay()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Calvin, that totally resolved my issue and I've learn a lot of how messing with dates with your code. Really thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you don't need to use an IF statement for this.
Just calculate the correct day indexes, and use modulus (%) to make sure you don't go outside your days array:

```
function calculateDay () {
            const days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
            let today = new Date();
            let currentDay = today.getDay();
            let trueDay = days[currentDay];
            let afterTom = days[((trueDay + 1) % days.length)];
            let dayNext = days[((trueDay + 2) % days.length)];
            } 
        }
```

But I'm not sure why you call the day + 1 afterTomorrow, isn't that the day tomorrow?